# If the date is the same then run a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm getting an issue that the arrays or not being filled.
 The correct date is set in the spreadsheet `29/09/2017`
I think it is because the texts don't match. See below for code:

The date is being set:

```
  // Format the date

var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");

var sendTheseEmail = [];
var sendTheseName = [];
var sendTheseLName = [];
var sendTheseBackup = [];
var sendTheseAdvocate = [];


for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
function findSend() {
  if(tsSheet.getRange("F" + i).getValue() == formattedDate){
   sendTheseEmail.push(tsSheet.getRange("D" + i).getValue())
   sendTheseName.push(tsSheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue())
   sendTheseLName.push(tsSheet.getRange("B" + i).getValue())
   sendTheseBackup.push(tsSheet.getRange("E" + i).getValue())
   sendTheseAdvocate.push(tsSheet.getRange("G" + i).getValue())
```

The logs show:

The date

```
[17-09-29 03:05:31:426 PDT] 29/09/2017
```

Then the array logs:

```
[17-09-29 03:05:31:427 PDT] []
[17-09-29 03:05:31:427 PDT] []
[17-09-29 03:05:31:428 PDT] []
[17-09-29 03:05:31:428 PDT] []
[17-09-29 03:05:31:429 PDT] []
```

If anyone could help that'd be great!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without any minimal runnable code, but I guess if you want to compare the date then just use `Utilities.formatDate` to format the date from that cell as well:

```js
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
var sendTheseEmail = [];
var sendTheseName = [];
var sendTheseLName = [];
var sendTheseBackup = [];
var sendTheseAdvocate = [];


for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  function findSend() {
    // Format the cell value before comparision
    if (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(tsSheet.getRange("F" + i).getValue()), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy") == formattedDate) {
      sendTheseEmail.push(tsSheet.getRange("D" + i).getValue())
      sendTheseName.push(tsSheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue())
      sendTheseLName.push(tsSheet.getRange("B" + i).getValue())
      sendTheseBackup.push(tsSheet.getRange("E" + i).getValue())
      sendTheseAdvocate.push(tsSheet.getRange("G" + i).getValue())
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to exactly match the dates because there are evaluated as strings.

Comment: Can you post how formatted date gets set and why the dates are so far in the future?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Thank you, the real question is why a spreadsheat value get converted into those botched date. Is there any parsing when the spreadsheat gets loaded into `tsSheet`?

Comment: I'm getting the sheet like this: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var tsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");